# Git Merge Undo and Switch To Previous Commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I have just committed my local changes with `git commit -m "commit 1"`

. Then, I did `git pull origin` to acquire changes from the remote branch. Then, during the merger, something went wrong. That is, after the merge commit, I do not see my changes. How can I revert to commit1 from the current one?

This commit is exactly one behind the current position of the HEAD if I do `git branch checkout` on this branch.

Comment: `git reset --hard commit_id`, use `git reflog` to see commits ids.

Comment: I have done. The problem is that now when I try to do git pull, the changes get pulled automatically and I do not have an option to merge them again. Should I be resetting the remote commits as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest and probably cleanest way to go is to rebase interactively:

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^
```

Alternatively,

```
git reset --hard commit-id
git push
```

You may have to `git push -f`.

Doesn't help you recover your local changes in this case, but in the future you can do the following to avoid the loss:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: A merge *cannot* lose changes: the local changeset (created by the commit) *cannot* be modified and will *not* be [randomly] lost. That is, the last bit of this answer is silly. Stashing is useful insofar as it pulls (or applies) a patch off of (or on to) the working directory.

Comment: I have done. The problem is that now when I try to do git pull, the changes get pulled automatically and I do not have an option to merge them again. Should I be resetting the remote commits as well?  That is, after git pull, locally, I end up with what seems like the remote version of the code that I was trying to override with my local changes.

Comment: By the way, when I do git reset --hard to the commit I want and then try git stash, it tells me that there are no changes to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

use `git reflog show` show to see the history of HEAD, the you can reset your HEAD to that commit (in your case probably `git reset HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: I know the number of commit and I know how to get the HEAD there. I am asking how to get rid of the latest commit so I can do git push again with proper changes.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. This is not what you wrote you wanted to do.

Comment: Yes, I should not have used "revert" as it is a loaded term with Git. I meant discard the new commit entirely.

Comment: You can still use my answer as your solution... just use a different {X}. Choose your commit number based on the reflog as I showed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only see what was your previous version temporarely, you can always checkout the `commit 1`

start by `git log` and find your commit hash

Then, checkout the commit:

```
git checkout acb1234
```

You will see the older version of you source.

If you really want to go back before your merge

```
git reset --hard acb1234
```

If you pushed your merge, what you can do is git revert:

```
git revert -m 1 1a2b3c # the merge hash
```